# Metal - Optimizing GPU matrix multiplication for memory latency

Tags: c++, matrix, gpu, gpgpu, metal

This is a pretty basic C++ question for computing matrix multiplication on a GPU. The following code is technically MSL, but the syntax is nearly identical.

Apple provides a [matrix multiplication example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MetalPartialSumsCompute/Listings/MetalMatrixMultiplication_MetalMatrixMulti_metal.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015013-MetalMatrixMultiplication_MetalMatrixMulti_metal-DontLinkElementID_20) for computing `A^T * B`. I'm looking for some help to modify it to simply compute `A * B`.

Each call to this shader operates on an 8 x 8 sector of `C`, and `gid` is the position of this sector in the grid. Here's the source:

```
// Note:
//
// (1) m is the number of rows in matrices A and C.
//
// (2) n is the number of columns in matrix A; number of rows in matrix B.
//
// (3) k is the number of columns in matrices B and C.
//
// (4) Matrix multiple computes C = A^T * B where A is m x n matrix (so
//     that, A^T is n x m), B is n x k .
//
// (5) pbytes is stride in bytes from row to another of matrix A.
//     pbytes should be multiple of 32, i.e. A is padded to be
//     M x k matrix where M > m and P is multiple of 8.
//
// (6) Similarly qbytes is stride in bytes from one row to another
//     of B, i.e. B is n x K matrix where K > k matrix where K is
//     multiple of 8.
//
// (7) The output matrix C is the M x K matrix.

typedef struct
{
    ushort m, k, n, pbytes, qbytes;
} MetalMatrixDim;


kernel void MatrixMultiply(const device float*       A    [[ buffer(0) ]],
                           const device float*       B    [[ buffer(1) ]],
                           device float*             C    [[ buffer(2) ]],
                           constant MetalMatrixDim&  dims [[ buffer(3) ]],
                           ushort2                   gid  [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{
    ushort m = dims.m;
    ushort k = dims.k;
    ushort n = dims.n;

    ushort pbytes = dims.pbytes;
    ushort qbytes = dims.qbytes;

    // Multiply gid by 8 to get the absolute position in C
    ushort2 gidIn = ushort2(gid.x << 3, gid.y << 3);

    if (gidIn.x >= m || gidIn.y >= k) return;

    const device float4* a = (const device float4*)(A + gidIn.x);
    const device float4* b = (const device float4*)(B + gidIn.y);

    C = (device float*)((device char*)C + gidIn.x*qbytes);

    device float4* c = (device float4*)(C + gidIn.y);

    const device float4* Bend = (const device float4*)((const device char*)B + qbytes*n);

    float4 s0  = 0.0f, s1  = 0.0f, s2  = 0.0f, s3  = 0.0f;
    float4 s4  = 0.0f, s5  = 0.0f, s6  = 0.0f, s7  = 0.0f;
    float4 s8  = 0.0f, s9  = 0.0f, s10 = 0.0f, s11 = 0.0f;
    float4 s12 = 0.0f, s13 = 0.0f, s14 = 0.0f, s15 = 0.0f;

    do
    {
        float4 aCurr0 = a[0];
        float4 aCurr1 = a[1];
        float4 bCurr0 = b[0];
        float4 bCurr1 = b[1];

        s0   += (aCurr0.x * bCurr0);
        s2   += (aCurr0.y * bCurr0);
        s4   += (aCurr0.z * bCurr0);
        s6   += (aCurr0.w * bCurr0);

        s1   += (aCurr0.x * bCurr1);
        s3   += (aCurr0.y * bCurr1);
        s5   += (aCurr0.z * bCurr1);
        s7   += (aCurr0.w * bCurr1);

        s8   += (aCurr1.x * bCurr0);
        s10  += (aCurr1.y * bCurr0);
        s12  += (aCurr1.z * bCurr0);
        s14  += (aCurr1.w * bCurr0);

        s9   += (aCurr1.x * bCurr1);
        s11  += (aCurr1.y * bCurr1);
        s13  += (aCurr1.z * bCurr1);
        s15  += (aCurr1.w * bCurr1);

        a = (device float4*)((device char*)a + pbytes);
        b = (device float4*)((device char*)b + qbytes);

    } while(b < Bend);

    c[0] = s0;  c[1] = s1;  c = (device float4*)((device char*)c + qbytes);
    c[0] = s2;  c[1] = s3;  c = (device float4*)((device char*)c + qbytes);
    c[0] = s4;  c[1] = s5;  c = (device float4*)((device char*)c + qbytes);
    c[0] = s6;  c[1] = s7;  c = (device float4*)((device char*)c + qbytes);
    c[0] = s8;  c[1] = s9;  c = (device float4*)((device char*)c + qbytes);
    c[0] = s10; c[1] = s11; c = (device float4*)((device char*)c + qbytes);
    c[0] = s12; c[1] = s13; c = (device float4*)((device char*)c + qbytes);
    c[0] = s14; c[1] = s15;
}
```

I've spent quite a bit of time on this, but the best I've come up with is a naive solution which doesn't take memory latency into account. Instead, I'm hoping to modify Apple's code to eliminate the transposition of `A`, while still allowing the GPU to optimize memory reads/writes.

Can someone help me out here?

**Edit:** Here's my (very) naive implementation. It executes roughly 100x slower than Apple's kernel:

```
int pbytes = (int)dims.pbytes;
int qbytes = (int)dims.qbytes;

for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    int aStart = (gidIn.y + row) * pbytes / 4;
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
        int cIdx = gidIn.y + (row * qbytes / 4) + gidIn.x + col;
        int bStart = gidIn.x + col;
        float sum = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < (pbytes / 4); i++) {
            float prod = A[aStart + i] * B[bStart + (i * qbytes / 4)];
            sum += prod;
        }
        C[cIdx] = sum;
    }
}
```

The issue with this implementation is that it does not optimize for memory access at all. Ideally, you would read and write as much data as possible at a time, allowing the compiler to vectorize the operation.

Comment: As you mentioned you already tried to implement a `A * B` version: Did you run it and compared the runtime to Apples `A^T * B` kernel?

Comment: @Shadow I updated the question with my code. I haven't compared the times on an identical set of data, but I am extremely certain that mine is much slower. The key lies in the way Apple reads - and then writes - several locations sequentially. This allows the compiler to perform the reads/writes concurrently. I don't claim to understand all their code (hence the question), but I was hoping that removing the transposition wouldn't be *too* difficult.

Comment: I took some time to have a closer look at Apples kernel. Only that after one minute I already got demotivated as the notes at the beginning of the file are very confusing - relating (4): if `A^T` is `n x m` and `B` is `n x k` we cannot compute `A^T * B`. (5): `A` has to be padded so that `pbytes` is a multiple of 32. But whats with that `P`? They probably meant `M`. But thats all wrong as this describes a padding of the columns and not the rows (cf. point (6)). And where did the `k` come from? If we use that `k`, a transposed `M x k` matrix still cannot be multiplied with a `n x K`matrix

Comment: @Shadow I agree, the notes are pretty inaccurate. Here's my best understanding of what's going on: according to [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/606/) (around 12:00), Metal is best optimized when you have each thread doing as much work as possible. This differs from most CUDA recommendations for matrix multiplication, where each thread only operates on one element of `C` and you make use of shared threadgroup memory for speed.

Comment: So Apple's implementation of `A^T * B` operates on 64 elements of `C`, and is written such that all memory reads happen sequentially and all writes happen sequentially, with the arithmetic in between. What I'm trying to accomplish is a similarly-optimized algorithm for `A * B`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144005/discussion-between-shadow-and-hundley).

Comment: (Copy of my last message in the chat:) Were you able to implement it? And does it perform well? If so, why don't answer your own question? It may help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

MetalPerformanceShaders framework has a builtin matrix multiplication kernel that you can just encode into your metal command buffer.  I recommend doing that instead of wasting a lot of time here.